# Floating divs and headline with vertical margin are wrongly aligned

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have following markup:

```
<div class="twocol float-left">
    <h4>left</h4>
    <p>first</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>

<div class="twocol">
    <h4>right</h4>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>foobar</p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.twocol {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

h4 {
    margin: 1em 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu5ZH/)

**Problem**

The headlines' vertical position should be equal, but "right" is `1 em` above "left". Why? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is due to collapsing margins.  By default there is some margin on the body.  When two margins meet the browser chooses the larger of the two and applies it.  When you float the one column this disrupts the collapsing margin and both margins are being applied.

I have added some background colors to your fiddle to illustrate this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Hu5ZH/2/

To learn more about collapsing margins:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: @Jrod Good anwswer, so another question.  From W3: "A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box."  Is this why the floated box's top was shifted down? http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

Answer (score 0):

add the `float-left`class to your right `div`

Comment: can you explain why the browsers renders it like that without adding float left to the right div?

Comment: @Alp because when you add 'float' to element , it "falls" from main flow and wraps all no-float element

Answer (score 0):

Give `float:left` to `.twcol`

```
   .twocol 
       {
        margin-right: 1em;
        float:left;
       }
```

Comment: can you explain why the browsers renders it like that without adding float left to the right div?

Answer (score 0):

Add the width of your column (width:50%) and relative positioned with float left (position:relative;float:left;) on your twocol class.

Might also want to use the "clearfix" method to clear out the two floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

add class float-left to right bar

```
<div class="twocol float-left">
  <h4>left</h4>
  <p>first</p>
  <p>second</p>
  <p>third</p>
</div>

<div class="twocol float-left">
  <h4>right</h4>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <p>foobar</p>
</div>​
```

Answer (score -1):

By adding

```
border : 1px solid transparent;
```

to `.twocols`, everything will be fine.
However, I can't figure out why.

Comment: It is because of collapsing margins.  Adding padding would also have the same effect.

Comment: @Jerska This should be a comment on the question, not an answer--just fyi

Comment: I've just read what you wrote. Nice explanation.  @AlexMA It might be a fix for those who want a quick solution.

Comment: True. But a dirty solution is still a solution.